# Error 14: Could not open CRS database

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyqgis

I am using Python Console and loading a Vector Layer using python commands. When the layer is added, QGIS first asks for the CRS to use, but I don't have all the CRS listed out to select the Reference system from and the "Error Log" shows the error as:

***> "Could not open CRS database C:/Program Files/QGISDufour/./resources/srs.db. 
Error(14): unable to open database file"***

Now what shall I do get this cleared. I cannot load my vector layer because of CRS problem.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for the edit, if you have any suggestion for the problem, would you please help me out?

Comment: I'm not a frequent user of QGIS and/or Coordinate Systems so I simply made sure that this had a `coordinate-system` tag on it so that it would be more likely to show up on the lists of those who are.